# Where are Adobe Fireworks CS6 textures located on my Win7 machine?

Tags: fireworks

I'm looking to use one of the not-so-bad textures on my site, but can't find it on my machine. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the actual files are in a hidden folder, so you'll need to [show those first](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/global/show-hidden-files-folders-extensions.html), then they should be in or near `C:Users/USERNAME/AppData/Roaming/Adobe/Fireworks CS6/Textures`.